# Could this be a problem for conversion rate?

Tags: user-behavior, conversion

I just started using a Skype similar application on my Android.
The application automatically imports your contacts and facebook friends to have them visible as callable contacts in the application.

However, to call them without charge, it's required that they have the application as well, same as with Skype.
Therefore there is an invite feature in the application, a button that says "Invite friends to call for free" (terrible button caption, I know...).

When you click that you open a dialogue that looks like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVx7EI.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

And here my issue begins. Personally I got off put by the description of the action. To me it seams very unclear whether clicking any of the buttons will move me to a new view to make selections of which friends I want to invite or whether the application will fire up a workflow that sends invitations too all of my contacts, something that I'm not that keen on.

My question is if this would be considered an efficient communication to users to invite new users? Or if it could actually hinder conversion rate, seeing as I as a user was not to keen clicking either of the buttons in fear of sending out a mass spam messages.

Never mind what the actions actually does, since knowing that erases the problem.

Comment: My question would be: where do I close it?

Comment: @Theraot well, it's an Android application. Android application rarely has on screen controls for *Close, Back, Cancel* since that's achieved by using the dedicated physical *Back* button that all Android devices have.

Answer (score 2):

My issue with the current design is that the mockup gives me an  impression that clicking on the buttons will immediately send a message to all my contacts or facebook friends asking them to install the app which might not be what people want. I would recommend an approach where you present a large call to action which invites the user to perform the action i.e. talk to your friends but the most important thing is **talk free**

Once you have got them to click the call to action button, present them with the option to individually invite their friends who might want to use the app. Also if possible, show which users already have the app so that the user gets a sense of security that other people also know about the app.

Given below is a rough mockup of the process flow

[image]